# Referring to just one person in an audience

Tags: phrase-choice

NOTE: I am not asking whether "audience" is a singular or plural word.

---

I am writing critical analyses of essays written by influential people. So, a sentence in my analysis could be: (in an essay protesting against governmental policies)

> **The reader** at this point feels guilty for supporting his government.

Now, what if I am critically analysing a *speech*? Surely, a speech has an audience and not just one reader. But, I still wish to refer to just one person, the same way as I did in the above sentence. One possible approach in my mind is:

> **Every person in the audience** at this point feels guilty for supporting his government.

But, it's a bit verbose imo. I hope there might be more elgant or entirely different expressions.

Comment: You're referring to "the reader" as a representative or typical reader?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo A general, common-place, ordinary reader.

Comment: One who is moved by the oratory.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Did you just stop in the middle of writing a complete sentence? To me the last comment feels an incomplete phrase imho.

Comment: It was a continuation of your comment.

Comment: One phrase parallel to "the reader" would be "a listener" or "an audience member".  The indefinite article remains singular without suggesting specificity, closer to "some typical listener" than "any listener" or "every listener"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is quite common to find the phrases **the reader** and **the audience** in literary criticism and textual analysis. Apart from the theoretical issues of approaching a text in terms of audience response, using the phrases is certainly acceptable and is standard behavior.

Comment: "The audience at this point feels guilty for supporting his government." doesn't seem right to me imho. What do I do with that "his"?

Comment: Change it to **this** or **that** or **the** or **their**.

Answer (score -1):

I haven't entirely understood what you mean, but it might be "*attender*".

Edit: Actually, simply "*listener*" might be appropriate.

Comment: Would the down-voter explain the reason?